# Visual studio code on Windows 10 with Rancher Desktop: unable to open folder in container: Docker returned an error code EACCES, message

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-10, rancher-desktop

On a Windows machine, I'm heavily using the "open folder in container" functionality of Visual Studio Code, with Docker managed by Rancher Desktop.
For this to work, I always run Visual Studio Code as administrator.

Since today, however, it doesn't work any more, and the "Docker returned an error code EACCES, message" is reported.

As a workaround, I changed the properties of

`C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\win32\bin\Docker.exe`

by unchecking the "Run this program as an administrator" checkbox:

[image]

This, however, seems to me not to be a good solution to the problem.

What is the proper way of fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but after performing the automatic upgrade to Docker 1.8.1 today, I noticed that the docker.exe excutable had moved to `C:\Program Files\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\win32\bin` on my machine.

Could it be that you are somehow still using an old version of `docker.exe`?